# SSH into IP Connected Linux Device using Windows 10

Tags: linux, windows-10, networking, ssh, putty

So I am trying to SSH into my local device (ip connected via  10.0.0 subnet) from Windows, and I can't seem to do it.

I plug in my device into my Linux laptop, running Ubuntu 16, and I type:

```
ssh root@10.0.0.202
```

and it works fine. However, when I plug the same device into my Windows laptop, and try to ssh (using Putty, Bitwise, or OpenSSH) it just times out.

What am I doing wrong? Why is it so easy on Linux, but not Windows?

---

Edit: I turned my firewall completely off and still get the same thing.
Edit2: When I run arp -a, I think I see the device, with auto IPV4 169.254.39.X -- but I can't ssh into that either. **It tells me: connection refused**

Comment: What kind of device are you talking about and why do you plug it into your laptop? A bit more information on your network topology would be helpful

Comment: @jvda I am the most complete n00b at networking haha But it is a radio that is running ubuntu 16. It has an ethernet port but that is it.